Laravel Flasher.io Display error not working
I am using this package.
https://php-flasher.io/laravel/
This code of mine works fine.
 flash()->success('Operation completed successfully.');
        return back();

But
<script>
            @if ($errors->any())
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)                 
                    flasher.error("{{$error}}");
                @endforeach
            @endif
</script>

but it doesn't show these error messages
show these error messages

This is completely wrong. Why you using it on js markup? You should try to receive it on blade, but even that you are flashing 'success' not the 'error'.
